# Struts2 is it possible to iterate to a specific index using struts iterator tag

Tags: struts2, iterator, struts

for example :

```
<s:iterator value="countries">
  <s:iterator value="cities">
    <s:property value="name"/>, <s:property value="[1].name"/><br>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

This will display

```
Wellington, New Zealand
Auckland, New Zealand
Moscow, Russia
Glasgow, Scotland
Edinburgh, Scotland
Stockholm, Sweden
```

I want to display

```
New Zealand
-----------
Wellington 
Auckland

Russia
------
Moscow

Scotland
--------
Glasgow 
Edinburgh ..

etc ..
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Please see this example:

Bean:

```
public class Country {
    private String [] cities;
    private String name;

    public String[] getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(String[] cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Action Class:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

    private Country [] countries;

    public String doCountryList() {

        countries = new Country[4];
        String [] cities = new String[] {"Wellington", "Auckland"};
        countries[0] = new Country();
        countries[0].setCities(cities);
        countries[0].setName("New Zealand");

        cities = new String[] {"Moscow"};
        countries[1] = new Country();
        countries[1].setCities(cities);
        countries[1].setName("Russia");

        cities = new String[] {"Glasgow", "Edinburgh"};
        countries[2] = new Country();
        countries[2].setCities(cities);
        countries[2].setName("Scotland");

        cities = new String[] {"Stockholm"};
        countries[3] = new Country();
        countries[3].setCities(cities);
        countries[3].setName("Sweden");

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Country[] getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(Country[] countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
}
```

Jsp:

```
    <s:iterator value="countries" var="country">
          <s:property value="#country.name"/><br/>
          --------------<br/>
          <s:iterator value="#country.cities" var="city">
               <s:property value="city"/><br>
          </s:iterator>
          <br/>
     </s:iterator>
```

If your bean design is of this type, you can implement the above style of usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with James, this should be in a data structure--as coded it looks brittle. If your arrays already exist as you want, you should just be able to move things to where you actually want them.

You should use a structure, but prefer collections over arrays (in pseudo-code):

```
class Country {
    String name
    List cities
    Country(name)
    Country(name, ... cities)
    void add(City)
}
```

Add some static imports and utilities:

```
Country c = country("Brobdingnag", 
                    city("Laputa"),
                    city("Balnibarbi"),
                    city("Luggnagg"));
```

The JSP becomes:

```
<s:iterator value="countries">
    ${name}<br/>
    --------------<br/>
    <s:iterator value="cities">
        ${name}<br/>
    </s:iterator>
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thank you both for the reply. I think , the only option with me is to change the bean. I was actually trying to find a way in the view during the iteration to make it possible with the current bean structure. But I was unable to get the index in the iterator to do the same. This seems to be the best way out for me. Thank you again for taking your time to look into this.